# Large 2-part of Tate–Shafarevich group over $\Bbb{Q}$ with small number of prime factor of discriminants

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, tate-shafarevich-groups

$\newcommand{\Sha}{\operatorname{Sha}}$Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve, and let $\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})$ denote the Tate–Shafarevich group of $E/\mathbb{Q}$. It is known that the 2-primary component $\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})[2]$ can become arbitrarily large as we vary $E$.

For example, Kramer found an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with discriminant $m(16m+1)$ and $\operatorname{\#Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})[2] \geq 2^{2k-2}$, where $k$ is the number of prime factors of $16m+1$ ("A family of semistable elliptic curves with large Tate–Shafarevich groups," Proceedings of the AMS, 89 (1983)).

This elliptic curve has a discriminant $\Delta_E$ with a very large number of prime factors.

However, is it possible to enlarge the 2-part of the Tate–Shafarevich group while keeping the number of prime factors of the discriminant small? Specifically, can we increase $\dim_2\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})[2] - \omega(\Delta_E)$ arbitrarily?

The largest value of $\dim_2\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})[2] - \omega(\Delta_E)$ that I am aware of is 4. If anyone knows of an example with a larger $\dim_2\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})[2] - \omega(\Delta_E)$, I would greatly appreciate the information.

Let $\omega(\Delta_E)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of $\Delta_E$. The following two elliptic curves have a small number of prime factors of their discriminants, $\omega(\Delta_E) = 2$, and $\dim_2\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})[2] - \omega(\Delta_E) = 4$:

1. $E_d: y^2 = x^3 + dx$ when we let $d$ be $p = 2^{2^k} + 1$, then $\Sha(E_{65537}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^2$. For more information, refer to the discussion on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151396/the-exponent-of-%D0%A8-of-y2-x3-px-where-p-is-a-fermat-prime).
2. Let $E_{p,n}: y^2 = x^3 + p^nx$ be an elliptic curve. According to LMFDB, for $(p,n) = (73,3)$, $\operatorname{\#Sha}(E_{p,n}) = 64$. This was mentioned in a MathOverflow discussion available [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454965/large-tate-shafarevich-group-of-an-elliptic-curve-with-the-form-e-p-ny2-x3).

Edited

In Table 2 of the document available at [Sza.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewodzicki/prace/Sza.pdf), the case of $(n,p) = (16,48)$ is cited as an example where $dim_2\Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})- \omega(\Delta_E) = 18 - 6 = 12$.
I'm also interested in the strong problem:$ord_2\#Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})- \omega(\Delta_E)$ can be arbitrary large ?

This should probably be considered a separate issue, so after giving it some thought on my own, I might ask you about it another time.

Comment: Partial answer: the answer is no if $E$ has a rational 2-torsion point, which is basically just an application of genus theory. In this case the 2-Selmer rank is bounded explicitly by $2^{\omega(\Delta_E)}$ (up to some fudge factor).

Comment: For $E$ without rational $2$-torsion, I would look for examples among those curves for which the $2$-torsion of the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(E[2])$ is large.

Comment: I think you are confusing $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_{2}} {\rm Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})[2]$ and the $2$-adic valuation of the order of ${\rm Sha}$. For the $n=16$, $p=48$ curve mentioned in your post, a $2$-descent says that the $2$-Selmer group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{4}$.

Comment: Could you provide the reference for your statement regarding the bound of the 2-Selmer group by genus theory, @Stanley Yao Xiao?